# Where did all the text go on mobile site? Elements not appearing on iPhone.

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile, emulation

I have created a website for my dad as a favour for putting me through design school. After uploading it to the network hosting site that my dad uses I discovered that when opening the site on my iPhone, all the text (or most of it) completely disappears. I am not sure what is doing this because when I test the site through Chrome Developer Tools, JsFiddle, etc it appears to be fine. The site is pretty simple so I am using Flexbox for the layout. Let me know if you need any other details.

I am not sure what is going on and would very much appreciate it if someone could take a poke around and point me in the right direction. I am providing a JsFiddle that includes the homepage html and the relevant CSS as well as posting it here. Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/ericvnwk/vfnejmw7/2/

The HTML:

```
<title>
  Fairfield Tree Nurseries Inc.</title>
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/hlp7xgg.js"></script>
<script>
  try {
    Typekit.load({
      async: true
    });
  } catch (e) {}

</script>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img class="logo" src="https://s1.postimg.org/1ic483yqhr/logo.png" alt="Fairfield Tree Nurseries Inc." width="80px" height="80px">
    <div class="title"><a href="index.html"> Fairfield Tree Nurseries Inc. </a>
</div>
    <nav class="navbar navtop">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="shipping.html">Shipping</a></li>
        <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="header-border">
  </div>

  <div class="main">

    <div class="fw-content fw-top">
      <div class="fw-image">
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/1ic4840vnj/welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome to Fairfield Tree Nurseries">
      </div>
      <div class="cntr-type">
        <h2> Welcome to </h2>
        <h1> Fairfield Tree Nurseries </h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="arrow">
      <div class="down-arrow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="fw-content below">
      <div class="fw-image">
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/1lvq5tqycf/about-home.jpg" alt="Welcome to Fairfield Tree Nurseries">
      </div>
      <div class="cntr-type">
        <h4 id="green"> We are a wholesale tree nursery producing field <br> grown nursery stock in the Lower Fraser Valley <br> community of Chilliwack, British Columbia. </h4>
        <div class="btn" id="green-btn">
          <a href="about.html">
            <h3>Learn More</h3></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fw-content">
      <div class="fw-image">
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/51y1xx3dpr/field-wide.jpg" alt="Field wide angle">
      </div>
      <div class="cntr-type up">
        <h4 class="shadow" id="white"> We offer an expanded product line to include a wide <br> range of field grown grafted conifers, specialty broadleaf <br> evergreen/deciduous shrubs and specimen plant material. </h4>
        <div class="btn btn-shadow" id="white-btn">
          <a href="products.html">
            <h3 class="">Discover More</h3></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hw-content hide">
      <div class="hw-left">
        <div class="cntr-type cntr-type-special">
          <h4 id="white"> Our products can be found throughout <br> North America and we pride ourselves in <br> providing expert service and support to all <br> of our clients, wherever they are. </h4>
          <div class="btn" id="white-btn">
            <a href="shipping.html">
              <h3>Shipping Info</h3></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hw-right">
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/2lbtizus33/leaves-sky-wide.jpg">
        <div class="cntr-type cntr-type-special">
          <h4 id="green"> We are located in the Lower <br> Fraser Valley community of Chilliwack, <br> British Columbia, Canada. </h4>
          <div class="btn" id="green-btn">
            <a href="location.html">
              <h3>View Map</h3></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fw-content hidden-content empty bkg-green">
      <div class="cntr-type">
        <h4 id="white"> Our products can be found throughout <br> North America and we pride ourselves in <br> providing expert service and support to all <br> of our clients, wherever they are. </h4>
        <div class="btn" id="white-btn">
          <a href="shipping.html">
            <h3>Shipping Info</h3></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fw-content hidden-content">
      <div class="fw-image">
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/2lbtizus33/leaves-sky-wide.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="cntr-type">
        <h4 id="green"> We are located in the Lower <br> Fraser Valley community of Chilliwack, <br> British Columbia, Canada. </h4>
        <div class="btn" id="green-btn">
          <a href="location.html">
            <h3>View Map</h3></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fw-content empty">
      <div class="cntr-type">
        <h4 id="green"> For more information or to place an order please contact us, <br> we would love to hear from you. </h4>
        <div class="btn" id="green-btn">
          <a href="contact.html">
            <h3>Contact Us</h3></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-main">
      <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/8ax5ukoq6n/logo-white.png">
      <!--<div class="logo-footer">
          </div> -->
      <div class="title" style="color: white;"><a href="index.html"> Fairfield Tree Nurseries </a></div>
      <nav class="navbar navfoot">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="shipping.html">Shipping</a></li>
          <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="copyright">
    <p> &copy; 2017 Fairfield Tree Nurseries Inc. All rights reserved.
  </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
   body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "proxima-nova-alt", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #707070;
}


/*================ NAV & HEADER STYLES + FOOTER ==================*/

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-border {
  background-color: #009948;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #009948;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.navbar {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 4vw;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #969696;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: .3s color;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: #009948;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.footer-main {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 80px 0px 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer h6 a {
  transition: .3s color;
}

.footer h6 a:hover {
  color: #009948;
}

.copyright {
  height: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #505050;
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, .5);
  padding: 40px 80px 10px 80px;
}

.copyright p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 400;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navfoot a {
  color: #707070;
  transition: .3s color;
}

.navfoot a:hover {
  color: white;
}


/*================ PAGES STYLES ===================*/

.main {
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*=============== Home PAGE ================*/

.fw-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.fw-top {
  border-top: 2px solid white;
}

.below {
  margin-top: -30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fw-image img {
  max-height: 600px;
}

.hw-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #009948;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.hw-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
}

.hw-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.hw-right img {
  height: 600px;
}

.cntr-type {
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
}

.up {
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.arrow {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.down-arrow {
  margin: -2px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid #009948;
}


/*================ TEXT STYLES ===================*/

h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
}

h5 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #009948;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
  text-align: left;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.currentlink a {
  color: #009948;
}

#green {
  color: #009948;
}

#grey {
  color: #2f2f2f;
}

#white {
  color: #fff;
}

.shadow {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/*================ BUTTON STYLES ====================*/

.btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#green-btn {
  background-color: rgba(0, 153, 72, 0);
  border-color: #009948;
  color: #009948;
  transition: .5s background-color, color;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#white-btn {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-color: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s background-color, color;
}

#green-btn:hover {
  border-color: #009948;
  background-color: rgba(0, 153, 72, 1);
  color: #fff;
}

#white-btn:hover {
  border-color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: #009948;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.btn-shadow {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


/*================================
  RESPONSIVE Styling
  ================================*/

@media screen and (min-width:500px) {
  .hidden-content {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
  .header {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: inherit;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .title {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .navbar {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar li {
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 7.5px 0 7.5px 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #009948;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: inherit;
    margin: 100px;
  }
  .navbar a:active {
    background-color: white;
    color: #009948;
  }
  .navtop {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  }
  .main {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .arrow {
    margin-top: -4px;
  }
  .cntr-type {
    padding: 0 5%;
  }
  .up {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .btn {
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .btn-shadow {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
  .hidden-content {
    display: flex;
  }
  .footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: inherit;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .footer-main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
    height: inherit;
  }
  .navfoot {
    background-color: #707070;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .navfoot li {
    border-color: #333;
  }
  .navfoot a {
    color: #333;
  }
  .copyright {
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  }
  .copyright p {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .questions {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .question-box {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  /*==============FONT STYLES==============*/
  h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
  }
  br {
    display: none;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) and (min-width:500px) {
  .header {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    height: inherit;
  }
  .navbar {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navtop {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  }
  .title {
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  .fw-content {
    height: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .fw-image {
    height: inherit;
  }
  .fw-image img {
    width: auto;
    height: 45vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .fw-top {
    border: none;
  }
  .cntr-type {
    padding: 0 10%;
  }
  .cntr-type-special {
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .cntr-type-special h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 32px;
  }
  .empty {
    height: 60vh;
  }
  .empty-s {
    height: 40vh;
  }
  h4 br {
    display: none;
  }
  .question-mark {
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {
  .navtop {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .bkg-green {
    background-color: #009948;
  }
  .hw-contact .contact-info {
    display: none;
  }
  .contact-info {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .fw-contact {
    padding: 15px 0 25px 0;
  }
  .contact-form {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .contact-form form {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:700px) {
  .hidden-content2 {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1240px) {
  .header {
    max-width: none;
  }
  .footer {
    max-width: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1580px) {
  .header {
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    max-width: 1500px;
  }
  .footer-main {
    max-width: 1500px;
  }
  .copyright {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `hidden-content` and `hide` classes which have `display: none` in them.

Comment: Is that what's affecting it? I just put those on some code blocks to switch between mobile and desktop versions of some sections. I will take a look and see if that is the problem later. Thanks

Comment: Well, everything in the divs with those classes will be hidden. So that is most likely your problem.

Comment: The content is duplicated though just in a mobile format so when it is on mobile it hides the other version of the content block and vice versa. Is there also a reason why this wouldn't appear when testing things through an emulator?

Comment: Those divs are just hidden for the sake of it switching between mobile and desktop versions. But my problem is that none of the text is appearing at all on the mobile version.